# Is there a sparkly/snuggly the crow equivalent trader in Bloodborne?

Tags: bloodborne

Considering this game is like a spiritual successor to Demon's Souls, and also carries many similarities to the Dark Souls games, does it feature an equivalent to Sparkly the Crow (Demon's Souls), Snuggly the Crow (Dark Souls), or Dyna and Tillo (Dark Souls 2)?

These were the unseen NPCs where you drop unwanted items in their bird's nest, and they squawk, say a few things, and swap your dropped item for something else in their inventory. This seems to be a recurring feature in the souls games so I'm curious as to whether it has made it through to Bloodborne too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question:
**No**, there is not an equivalent system.

However, you can use insight, the ingame currency, to buy items.

Sources:
"Items in Bloodborne are found in game *[...]* through trade with insight, or from chests. "
This site mentions nothing about traders, and a wiki would have mentioned so.

Comment: The insight messengers function just as a normal merchant, not like the crows in the question. Insight is used just as another currency.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I stated in my answer that you **cannot** trade items, like the question asked. I was merely adding that small amount of extra information in order to assist the poster. I answered his question, dealt with the information in his bounty, but added extra information. I have edited to clarify, and the answer is now more concise with all the applicable information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to drop an item in bloodborne.
I think that if there is such a thing as item trading it won't work like it did in the previous games.

Comment: How do you know this? Source please, unless you've played through the whole game... which would be barely possible by this point.